# I'm getting N/A when I run my code in the date column

Tags: r, dataset, r-markdown, markdown, na

I'm having trouble changing the date and time format . I get "Not applicable" in the date column, when submitting my code . Sorry in advance for this basic and nooby question.

```
input data

#daily_activity table

# Id #  #ActivityDate# #totalsteps# #total distance# #trackerdistance#
1503960366  4/12/2016   13162           8.50            8.50    
1503960366  4/13/2016   10735           6.97            6.97    
1503960366  4/14/2016   10460           6.74            6.74    
1503960366  4/15/2016   9762            6.28            6.28    
1503960366  4/16/2016   12669           8.16            8.16    
1503960366  4/17/2016   9705            6.48            6.48    

# daily_sleep tabel 

# Id #      # SleepDay # # sleeprecords #  #minuteasleep # # timeinbed #
1503960366  4/12/2016 0:00     1                 327             346
1503960366  4/13/2016 0:00     2                 384             407
1503960366  4/15/2016 0:00     1                 412             442
1503960366  4/16/2016 0:00     2                 340             367
1503960366  4/17/2016 0:00     1                 700             712
1503960366  4/19/2016 0:00     1                 304             320
```

```
When I run the code I receive this table

#daily_activity table
# Id #          #date#   #totalsteps#  #total distance# #trackerdistance#
1503960366  2016-04-12  13162          8.50              8.50   
1503960366  2016-04-13  10735          6.97              6.97   
1503960366  2016-04-14  10460          6.74              6.74   
1503960366  2016-04-15  9762           6.28              6.28   
1503960366  2016-04-16  12669          8.16              8.16   
1503960366  2016-04-17  9705           6.48              6.48   
     

# daily_sleep tabel 

## Id ## ## date ## ## sleeprecords ##  ## minuteasleep ## ## timeinbed ##
1503960366  <NA>           1                   327              346
1503960366  <NA>           2                   384              407
1503960366  <NA>           1                   412              442
1503960366  <NA>           2                   340              367
1503960366  <NA>           1                   700              712
1503960366  <NA>           1                   304              320
```

This is the code:

```
# I started by cleaning and renaming columns 
clean_names(daily_activity)
daily_activity<- rename_with(daily_activity, tolower)
clean_names(daily_sleep)
daily_sleep <- rename_with(daily_sleep, tolower)

# I want to clean date-time format for daily_activity and daily_sleep because I will merge both data frames.

daily_activity <- daily_activity %>% 
  rename(date= activitydate) %>%
  mutate(date= as_date(date, format= "%m/%d/%Y"))

daily_sleep <- daily_sleep %>%
  rename(date= sleepday) %>%
  mutate(date= as_date(date, format= "%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p", tz= Sys.timezone()))
```

For daily_activity it's normal, but I'm facing trouble with daily_sleep

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a case of `format` not matching your column format i.e. `lubridate::as_date("2021-23-05 01:05:02:356", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
[1] NA`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this then. As you don't have the seconds and the 0:00 doesn't really add anything.

If you did want to retain the H:MM I've added that option too.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union


tribble(
  ~Id, ~SleepDay, ~sleeprecords, ~minuteasleep, ~timeinbed,
  1503960366, "4/12/2016 0:00", 1, 327, 346,
  1503960366, "4/13/2016 0:00", 2, 384, 407,
  1503960366, "4/15/2016 0:00", 1, 412, 442,
  1503960366, "4/16/2016 0:00", 2, 340, 367,
  1503960366, "4/17/2016 0:00", 1, 700, 712,
  1503960366, "4/19/2016 0:00", 1, 304, 320
) |>
  mutate(
    date = str_remove(SleepDay, " 0:00"),
    date = mdy(date), # You use either this line OR the next line ... either works
    # date = as_date(date, format= "%m/%d/%Y")
    )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>           Id SleepDay       sleeprecords minuteasleep timeinbed date      
#>        <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl> <date>    
#> 1 1503960366 4/12/2016 0:00            1          327       346 2016-04-12
#> 2 1503960366 4/13/2016 0:00            2          384       407 2016-04-13
#> 3 1503960366 4/15/2016 0:00            1          412       442 2016-04-15
#> 4 1503960366 4/16/2016 0:00            2          340       367 2016-04-16
#> 5 1503960366 4/17/2016 0:00            1          700       712 2016-04-17
#> 6 1503960366 4/19/2016 0:00            1          304       320 2016-04-19

# And if you wanted the time too:
tribble(
  ~Id, ~SleepDay, ~sleeprecords, ~minuteasleep, ~timeinbed,
  1503960366, "4/12/2016 0:00", 1, 327, 346,
  1503960366, "4/13/2016 0:00", 2, 384, 407,
  1503960366, "4/15/2016 0:00", 1, 412, 442,
  1503960366, "4/16/2016 0:00", 2, 340, 367,
  1503960366, "4/17/2016 0:00", 1, 700, 712,
  1503960366, "4/19/2016 0:00", 1, 304, 320
) |>
  mutate(date = mdy_hm(SleepDay))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>           Id SleepDay    sleeprecords minuteasleep timeinbed date               
#>        <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1 1503960366 4/12/2016 …            1          327       346 2016-04-12 00:00:00
#> 2 1503960366 4/13/2016 …            2          384       407 2016-04-13 00:00:00
#> 3 1503960366 4/15/2016 …            1          412       442 2016-04-15 00:00:00
#> 4 1503960366 4/16/2016 …            2          340       367 2016-04-16 00:00:00
#> 5 1503960366 4/17/2016 …            1          700       712 2016-04-17 00:00:00
#> 6 1503960366 4/19/2016 …            1          304       320 2016-04-19 00:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you !! I did what you said but I still had the same problem. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: I did that, thanks for helping!

Comment: Sure I'll do that.